# Is it possible to force PowerPoint in preseter view via CLI or RegKey

Tags: powerpoint

I have an Application which - among other things - opens an uploaded PowerPoint Presentation in Presentation view. For that I use the command line switch:

```
"c:\program files\microsoft office\officexx\POWERPNT.exe" /S "MyFile.pptx"
```

As long as its a single monitor setup this works great. But now I'm looking for a possibility to use a dual Monitor setup with extended display, so people can use the PowerPoint presenter view on their main monitor.

Does anybody know of a command line switch or registry key that forces PowerPoint to *always* open with the Presentation on secondary display and preview on the primary, even if the presentation setup in PowerPoint (which I have no access to) is set to single Monitor display or preview on secondary monitor?

Comment: This may vary by PPT version, but in PPT2016, I can go to the Slide Show tab and put a check next to Presenter View.  I just tested this on a single-monitor laptop and when I started the slide show, it displayed on the laptop's screen, of course; ignored the Presenter View setting. I opened the same presentation in PPT 2010 on a two monitor system and it played in Presenter View.  Presenter View or no is a per-presentation setting, not something that you can change via registry, though.

Comment: Yes, I know it's part of the presentation settings. But I was hoping for a way to overrule the settings inside the presentation, as I have access to the laptop where it is shown, but not the presentation itself.

Comment: If your application can open the presentation via automation rather than CLI, you can set the current presentation to use Presentation view with this:  ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView = True

Comment: That's an very promising idea, but my application is a node.js/electron one, and I have no idea how I could open external files without CLI.